# React app Not Working on localhost:3000 even it is compiling with zero error and displays on title on localhost , doesn't display any content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localhost, url-routing, web-development-server

I am building a new website using react. It was working smoothly on local host but later on I made some changes and it stopped working  it was like when I go on localhost:3000 it shows only website title and doesn't display any content of home page. I know there might be an error in my routing  but I couldn't find it or may be something else. my codes of package.json and app.js are following:

```
{
  "name": "React",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "get-youtube-id": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-countup": "^6.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

//now app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages';

// structure of pages are src/pages and then named pages and one is index.js which is named Component home.
import Events from './pages/events';
import Gallary from './pages/gallary';
import Register from './pages/register';
import Sponsors from './pages/sponsors';
import Team from './pages/team';
import Ca from './pages/ca';

function App() {
return (
    <Router>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/' exact element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/team' element={<Team />} />
        <Route path='/events' element={<Events />} />
        <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
        <Route path='/gallary' element={<Gallary />} />
        <Route path='/sponsors' element={<Sponsors />} />
        <Route path='/ca' element={<Ca />} />
        
    </Routes>
    </Router>

    
);
};

export default App;
```

Navbar links

```
<Nav>
      
        <Bars />
        
        <a style={logo} href='/' alt="logo"><img  src='logo.png' style={logo}/></a>
        <NavMenu>

        <NavLink to="/about" >
            About
          </NavLink>
        
          <NavLink to="/events" >
            Events
          </NavLink>
          
          <NavLink to="/sponsors" >
            Sponsors
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/ca"> 
          CA
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/team" >
            Teams
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/gallary" >
            Gallary
          </NavLink>
          {/* <NavLink to='/sign-up' activeStyle>
            Sign Up
          </NavLink> */}
          {/* Second Nav */}
          {/* <NavBtnLink to='/sign-in'>Sign In</NavBtnLink> */}
        </NavMenu>
        <NavBtn  style={register}>
          <NavBtnLink  >Register</NavBtnLink>
        </NavBtn>
      </Nav>
```

Comment: Try removing `<Router></Router>` from `function App() {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

To debug your app I would try the following:

1. Review the changes since the last time your app worked
2. Look in the dev Console in Chrome for potential errors